# React Native: Not asking for push permission on Android (OneSignal)

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions, user-permissions

I just installed the OneSignal package and set it up like it is described in the [docs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup). However, OneSignal **always** has/gets permissions from the user although there is no popup coming app asking the user for permissions. Maybe thats the usual way Android works but I am used to a popup asking for permissions (I am an iOS user).

Isn't Android asking the user for push notification permissions? Is that usual? And is that even **machting with the GDPR regulations**?

Or is all I need the `AndroidManifest.xml` which is taking care of asking for permissions?

Cause when I am installing my `.apk` on my test device Android **IS NOT** asking for further permissions although in the `AndroidManifest.xml` I am asking for push notification permission and location permissions!

This is the install screen:
[image]

This is the OneSignal code for the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<!-- Optional - Add the necessary permissions (Choose one of those) -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> <!-- Approximate location - If you want to use promptLocation for letting OneSignal know the user location. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> <!--  Precise location If you want to use promptLocation for letting OneSignal know the user location. -->

<!-- End optional permissions -->


<application ....>
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="OneSignal Example"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"> <!-- Add this attribute to your main activity -->
  </activity>
    .....
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android you only have to ask for permissions that they class as **dangerous**.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

> Only dangerous permissions require user agreement. The way Android
>   asks the user to grant dangerous permissions depends on the version of
>   Android running on the user's device, and the system version targeted
>   by your app.

You can find a table here that lists of permissions that are currently classed as **dangerous**.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#permission-groups

Push Notifications is clearly missing from this list so you do not need to ask the user for permission to send them push notifications.

With regard to any other permissions, if OneSignal wants access to them and they are classed as dangerous (e.g. location) then the only way for them to get it is to show a dialog requesting the permission to access that information. Otherwise they won't have access to that information.

In iOS the system of permissions is much more rigorously controlled and before you do most things you have to ask permission.